# Statistical relationship with both dependent and independent variables percentages that sum to 1

Tags: correlation, spss, percentage, compositional-data

I'm trying to see if there is any relationship between the market share of a company (dependent variable) and the "tweet share" of this company (independent variable). The tweet share of a company is simply the amount of tweets about this company divided by the amount of all tweets about all companies that are in the same industry. So for example if Nike has a 40% tweet share in the sneaker industry this means that 40% of the tweets about sneakers are about Nike. I have data for the first three quarters of 2015.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to check for statistical relationship since both variables are percentages that sum to 1. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: But you are not using both percents in the analysis, are you?

Comment: @NickCox Yes I am.

Comment: @NickCox Although I could use the amount of Tweets in stead of the tweet share. But the dependent variable remains a percentage that sums to 1, the market share.

Comment: I doubt you mean what you say. If you have two predictors with constant sum, good software will show throw one of them out.

Comment: @NickCox Then I misunderstood your question. Only one predictor has a constant sum (equal to 1). But the dependent variable has a constant sum equal to 1 as well.

Comment: What I mean by constant sum is that (e.g.) $x_1 + x_2 = $ constant. Again, you can't mean that $x = $ constant. If $\sum x =$ constant, I don't see that as a problem.

Comment: @NickCox I mean ∑x = constant, since all tweet shares together will always be 100%.

Comment: Why should it be a problem? It's always true that the sum over observations of each variable is a constant, and that constant being 100 or 1 I don't think is special. To see this, notice that you could always just replace each percent by the corresponding amount by multiplying by the total. You would just change the coefficients of a regression, but there is no statistical problem in using percents rather than total so far as I can see. It's a units of measurement detail (important though that is for interpretation).

Comment: @NickCox, why not develop that into an answer, so that this doesn't get counted as unanswered?

Comment: I think the question is substantive.  If $s_{it}$ is share of company $i$ at time $t$, then $\sum_i s_{it}=1$, and the correlation matrix of the vector $\left( s_{1t},s_{2t}, \ldots s_{Nt} \right)$ is singular.  It's not accidental that  $\sum_i s_{it}=1$.  It's inherent.  It must happen for each and every observation (observations being indexed by $t$).

Comment: @gung Thanks for the suggestion. I'll flesh out my comments as an answer at some point next week.

Answer (score 0):

Since your output lies on $[0,1]$ you should be able to do a simple GLM with support $[0,1]$, the most common being logit or probit links (don't do this actually, the interpretation isn't correct as your independents are also bounded, let me have another think about it). I don't think having dependency inside the independent variable really matters, it is dependency across independent variables which is the problem.

The only problem you might face is determining how many companies you should include, with the problem being due to your constraint, when $n$ becomes large more observations are essentially going to be $(0,0)$ (a lot of small companies have 0 twitter share and 0 market share), which will both greatly skew your coefficients and greatly increase their p-values (as they are all centered around the same value).

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the data / problem. If you have 3 options that must sum to 1, you can list any 2 & the 3rd will be completely determined. This isn't a standard GLM w/ support on [0,1] type situation. These are compositional data; there are special methods for them.

Comment: Does it matter if the options you're talking about are in the dependent variable, the independent variable, or both?

Comment: The methods are related, but there are distinct options depending on whether you are talking about X or Y, I believe. @NickCox is much more expert on the topic than I am.

Comment: I was just thinking, if the constraint is on the dependent, than this wouldn't really be different to a GLM right? Since you can use a straightforward GLM from the multinomial family, on say categorical data, where the data satisfies exactly as you say, when you define $n-1$ values of the variable, the last value is completely determined.

And if the constraint is on the independent, that shouldn't really matter at all from how I'm thinking about it, but I could be very wrong.

Comment: As I understand the OP's situation, the dependent variable shouldn't be considered a percentage, but as a multinomial. That's correct.

Comment: So then multinomial regression should be fine?

Comment: I think that's part of it, but there may be more. Or it may be that the OP is just a bit confused & needs more cleared up, but multinomial LR is all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a proportional regression model would be appropriate here with an appropriate choice of linke function.  In SPSS Statistics, this can be done with the STATS PROPOR REGR extension command, which can be installed via the Extensions > Extension Hub menu.